# Using coord_*() functions in ggplot in a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code:

```
library(tidiverse)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + geom_col()
```

I need to rotate every single bar for example with 10º degrees to the right. As this figure bellow:
[image]

I think I will need some `coord_*()` function. But, how can I do that?

Any help?

Comment: Please explain why one would *need* to do that. Maybe that will broaden the options to deal with the real underlying problem.

Comment: My chart has multiple bars. This would be a visual effect of my chart. I will use this answer to make a bar chart rotate with other elemnts in my chart. This is possible in Adobe Illustrator but how canI achieve this result in ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach, where you adjust the data outside of ggplot. I'm not sure what you call the transformation: it's not strictly a rotation more a conditional rotation or translation; i.e. the vertical lines rotate but the horizonal lines translate.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(var = letters[1:4],
                 val = runif(4, 1, 10))

ggplot(df, aes(var, val))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

```r
rot_deg  <- 10

df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(x_shift = tan(pi * rot_deg / 180) * val,
         x0 = 0:3,
         x1 = x0 + 0.9,
         x2 = x1 + x_shift,
         x3 = x0 + x_shift,
         y0 = 0,
         y1 = 0,
         y2 = df$val,
         y3 = df$val) %>% 
  select(-c(val, x_shift)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-var, names_pattern = "(.)(.)", names_to = c("coord", "seq")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = coord, values_from = value)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, group = var))+
  geom_polygon()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is exactly the output I want. I was trying with `coord_*()` function